# npm returns "Permission denied" in CircleCI build

Tags: ubuntu, npm, circleci

How to fix this error? I've updated CircleCI to 2.0 and now can't run tests.

```
> npm test

sh: 1: npm: Permission denied
```

How I can use `sudo` or something else?

`circle.yml`

```
    machine:
  node:
    version: 8.9.1
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
    - sudo apt update
    - sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
    - sudo easy_install --upgrade six
    - sudo pip install --upgrade urllib3==1.21.1
    - sudo pip install --upgrade pip
    - sudo pip install --upgrade blessed
    - sudo pip install awsebcli==3.12.3 --ignore-installed six pyyaml
deployment:
  production:
    branch: production
    commands:
      - bash ./deploy_prod.sh
      - eb deploy stmi-production
  staging:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - bash ./deploy_staging.sh
      - eb deploy stmi-dev
```

`config.yml`

version: 2

```
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/systemsthinkinginstitute/stmi-test-web
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    docker:
    - image: circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37
      command: /sbin/init
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
    - run:
        working_directory: ~/systemsthinkinginstitute/stmi-test-web
        command: nvm install 8.9.1 && nvm alias default 8.9.1
    - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
        - v1-dep-master-
        - v1-dep-
    - run: sudo sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
    - run: sudo apt update
    - run: sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
    - run: sudo easy_install --upgrade six
    - run: sudo pip install --upgrade urllib3==1.21.1
    - run: sudo pip install --upgrade pip
    - run: sudo pip install --upgrade blessed
    - run: sudo pip install awsebcli==3.12.3 --ignore-installed six pyyaml
    - run: rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.aws
    - run: if [ -z "${NODE_ENV:-}" ]; then export NODE_ENV=test; fi
    - run: export PATH="~/systemsthinkinginstitute/stmi-test-web/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
    - run: npm install
    - save_cache:
        key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
        paths:
        - vendor/bundle
        - ~/virtualenvs
        - ~/.m2
        - ~/.ivy2
        - ~/.bundle
        - ~/.go_workspace
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.cache/bower
        - ./node_modules
    - run: npm test
    - store_test_results:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
    - store_artifacts:
        path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
```

Comment: May we see your `config.yml` edited into your question, appropriately formatted?

Comment: Please also remove the image in your post, and replace it with the text equivalent. Text trapped in images is not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines, and if you can use the text instead, that may help your readers help you.

Comment: What Docker image are you using?

Comment: @halfer, i've updated question

Comment: OK, much better, but I can't see `better-npm-run` in your YAML config?

Comment: @halfer It's in package.json

Comment: Might be worth showing that in your question, then? `:-)`

Comment: @halfer also i have `config.yml` that contains `-run: npm test` I've changed it to  `-run:sudo npm test` but it's doesnt work

Comment: @halfer `-run:sudo npm test` doesnt work for me

Comment: Please roll your question back - readers need to see you're using the Machine executor. You can add your additional material in at the end.

Comment: @FelicianoTech `circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37` it was by default

Comment: I'm very confused. The config in your question isn't using that nor is it a CircleCI 2.0 config.

Comment: @FelicianoTech, My bad. I've added also `config.yml`

Answer (score 0):

To run **"better-npm-run test"** in super user, you have to add `sudo` at the beginning:

```
$ sudo better-npm-run test
```

*user/password is required to exec by sudo*

Comment: `"scripts": { "test": "sudo better-npm-run test" }` Like that?

Comment: Yous should login as root in your terminal.